# Record Thingsboard telemetry history

Tags: thingsboard

I'm looking for a widget that will log my devices' incoming telemetry messages. I have a Key for Power whose value is either on or off. I want to record the date that this value changes and have it on a dashboard. Alarms don't seem to work as they display my current power status instead of what it was when it triggered the alarm.

Any suggestions?.. thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Add Widget/Charts/State Chart. this shows digital state over time.